# Передвижение виджета в окне

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, keypressevent

Как в этом коде сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на стрелки передвигался виджет влево, вправо, верх, вниз?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title = "PyQt5 Window"
    self.top = 100
    self.left = 100
    self.width = 680
    self.height = 500

    self.InitWindow()

def InitWindow(self):
    self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

    self.frame = QFrame(self)
    self.x, self.y = self.frame.pos().x(), self.frame.pos().y()
    self.x = 10
    self.y = 10

    self.frame.setGeometry(self.y, self.x, 200, 200)
    self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: black')
    self.show()

def keyPressEvent(self, e):

    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
        self.x += 10

if __name__ == '__main__':

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "PyQt5 Window"
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 500

        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: black')
        self.x, self.y = self.frame.pos().x(), self.frame.pos().y()
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10

        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.frame.setGeometry(self.x, self.y,  200, 200)    # self.x, self.y

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Right:
            self.x += 10

            self.InitWindow()                                # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':

    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо работает!

Comment: В keyPressEvent вместо `self.InitWindow` можно было `self.frame.move(self.x, self.y)`